# How i can to add a significant 0 to int?

Tags: java, numbers, int

Help me, how to add a significant 0 to number variable (int, float, ecc)?

```
int s = 0; -> 00
int m = 0; -> 00
int h = 0; -> 00
```

Comment: What are doing with the output?  Printing it?  Creating a string?

Comment: Your choice of variable names suggests you are implementing 'time'. Surely, there must be some class for that already in Java? Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 8):

You can't add significant 0's to numbers; that is an aspect of how they are DISPLAYED, not the values themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. However, you can change the way it's *displayed*, use [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String res = String.format("%02d", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't mather when you do calculations. But another way of doing this would be:

```
int s = 10;
System.out.println((s > 9)? s : "0" + s);
s = 0;
System.out.println((s > 9)? s : "0" + s);
```

**Output:**

```
> 10
> 00
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can't do that. 
Try

```
int v = 1;
String value = (v<=9)?"0"+v:v+"";
System.out.println(value);
```

OR 
you can use `String.format("%02d", v);`

*Output*

```
01
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class which contains an integer value and a number of significant zeros. Then you can override the `toString()` method in order to convert it to a string when you need to display it:

```
public class MyInteger{
    private int value;
    public int numOfZeros = 3; // default number of significant zeros
    public MyInteger(int val){
        this.value = val;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String format = new String("%0"+numOfZeros+"d");
        String s = new String(""+value);
        return String.format(format,s);
    }
}
```

In this way when you append this object to a string it will automagically converted in a string with the desired number of significant digits.